# Callout button crashes app - MapKit

Tags: ios, ios6, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

> UICalloutView willRemoveSubview:]: message sent to deallocated instance;

This only happens when I tap the callout button, but not on the first and not on the 2nd tap, but from the 3rd tap. So I tap the custom `AnnotationView`, callout pops, thats good. I tap it again, callout pops, all good. I tap another one, boom crash with that message. It only happes if is set the right accesoryview to be a button.

One key aspect to keep in mind..only happens in iOS 6... (go figure).

I am really stuck on this one – some help would be appreciated.

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[RE_Annotation class]])
{
    RE_Annotation *myAnnotation = (RE_Annotation *)annotation;

    static NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"annotationIdentifier";

    RE_AnnotationView *newAnnotationView = (RE_AnnotationView *)[mapViews dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];


    if(newAnnotationView)
    {
        newAnnotationView.annotation = myAnnotation;
    }
    else
    {
        newAnnotationView = [[RE_AnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
    }

    return newAnnotationView;
}
return nil;
```

Also, this is my `initwithannotation` method:

```
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{

    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if(self)
    {

    RE_Annotation *myAnnotation = annotation;

    self = [super initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kWidth, kHeight);

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    annotationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_pin_pink.png"]];

    annotationView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kWidth - 2 *kBorder, kHeight - 2 * kBorder);



    [self addSubview:annotationView];

    [annotationView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

    self.canShowCallout = YES;

     self.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight] retain]; ///if i take it out it doesnt crash the app. if i leave it it says that message
    }

    return self ;

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using? It is impossible to help without seeing what you are doing.

Comment: my code is too long to fit :(

Comment: Don't post all of your code, just the relevant sections, for example the code which handles your map annotations.

Answer (score 1):

In the `initWithAnnotation` method, there is this line:

```
self.rightCalloutAccessoryView = 
    [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight] retain]; 
///if i take it out it doesnt crash the app. if i leave it it says that message
```

By "it", you must be referring to the `retain` and this implies the app is not using ARC.

Based on that, you should make the following corrections:

- In `viewForAnnotation`, you need to `autorelease` the view when you alloc+init it otherwise there's a leak:

  ```
  newAnnotationView = [[[RE_AnnotationView alloc] 
      initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation 
      reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier] autorelease];
  ```
- In `initWithAnnotation`, remove the `retain` when creating the callout button since `buttonWithType` returns an auto-released object (and you don't want to over-retain it):

  ```
  self.rightCalloutAccessoryView = 
      [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
  ```

Another possibly unrelated issue is that in `initWithAnnotation`, the code is calling `super initWithAnnotation` twice.  This seems unnecessary and may be harmful.  Remove the second call.

The above changes at least fix the issues with the code shown.  However, there may be other, similar memory-management related issues in the rest of the app that may still cause crashes.  Check and solve all issues reported by Analyzer.

Regarding the fact that "it only happens in iOS 6": iOS 6 may be less forgiving of memory-management errors or an internal change in the SDK may be exposing or manifesting these errors earlier.  Regardless, the above fixes are necessary.

An unrelated point is there should be no need to manually create a `UIImageView` and `addSubview` it to the annotation view.  You can just set the annotation view's `image` property.

Comment: Alright. Shall do. Thanks a lot for the feedback. i did try with with the image property of the annotationview..and idd the init 2 times is a bad practice and is actually a typo...and indeed i forgot to release the annotation. i will make the apropriate changes and tell u...to be fairly honest i doubt it they will change something but nonetheless thanks a lot for ur time and i will get back.

Comment: As suspected..doesn`t  seem to have any effect.